# Using javascript ajax to call php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, call

I am trying to use localization in javascript where localization strings are stored in a php file and get_string() function is used to get the localized values in php. I've written a script called alertpopup.php

```
$alertmessage = $_POST['msg'];

switch($alertmessage)
{
    case '1':
        $alertmessage = get_string('first');
        break;
    case '2':
        $alertmessage = get_string('second');
        break;
    case 'deletecomment':
        $alertmessage = get_string('random');
        break;  
}

echo json_encode(Array('Message' => $alertmessage));
```

and a script in javascript to get value from this php script:-

```
            var answer;
        $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        data: "msg=1",
        url: "alertpopup.php",
        success: function(data) {
        var alertmsg = $.parseJSON(data);

            if (alertmsg.Message != null) {
                answer = confirm(alertmsg.Message);
                document.location.reload();
            }

        }
       });
        if(answer) {
                     something
                }
                else{
                    something else
                }
```

However, I keep getting error:-
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'parseJSON'

Can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using?

The [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) states that `parseJSON` was added in v1.4.1. Make sure you're not using an older version.

Comment: jquery-1.7.min.js so I am assuming 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing following code

```
var alertmsg = $.parseJSON(data);
```

with

```
var alertmsg = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

**EDIT:**

OR

School days method :)

```
var alertmsg = eval(data);
```

Some people may not agree with this due to some security or some thing like, but give it a try.

Comment: what is the result if alert the data variable, what you can see in dialogue box?
`alert(data);`

Comment: I added alert(data) after if(confirm(data.Message)) in answer by bipen and it shows the following in the message box:-
{"Message":"first"}

Comment: I have added a new way to parse json text, give it a try, and if possible email me your code, with html file and jQuery library you are using.
Have you tested your previous code on different browser?

Answer (score 0):

since you are getting the result of an ajax call in json... you don't need to parse the json there...

remove the `parseJson()` and try

**UPDATED**

```
var answer;
    $.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    data: "msg=1",
    dataType: "json",   //added
    url: "alertpopup.php",
    success: function(data) {

        if (data.Message != null) {
              if (confirm(data.Message)) {
                   something
               }else{
                   something else  
               }
            document.location.reload();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't show the error anymore but the something part of my if(answer) does not work either and it works if I just use the something without the script to get localized values.

Comment: Ok. This is what I am trying to do:- In place of current script in javascript, if I put var answer = confirm('This is non-localized message'), a popup with this message will appear. However, I am trying to display a popup with localized message and do something when user clicks ok. I have not included that part of the script but I can do so if that might help but its not really that related.

Comment: No. This removes the error but no popup is appearing either. If I just do var answer = confirm('This is non-localized message'); if(answer) {
                     something
                }
                else{
                    something else
                }        the popup appears as expected and the something part also works

Comment: No.The popup is still not appearing.

Comment: i think it is because of the reload() function ... see if ur page reloads before the popup shows... if yes... thn u better keep the reload function inside the if/else condition

Comment: When it was outside, the page was reloading but now that I have put it inside, even that stopped happening. Makes me wonder if it is even entering the if else loop now.

Comment: When I removed the check to test if data is empty, it entered the loop but data was still not read correctly. It showed a popup box saying undefined.

Comment: ok this is getting interesting...`console.log(data.Message)` and check in your firebug console... if your are getting the right message or not... :)

Comment: try adding datatype in your ajax call...`dataType: "json",`  check my eidted answer